# CSS triangle changing display value with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got this html

```
<div id="slideMenu">
    <div id="slideM1" onmouseover="colorM(1)">Something 1</div>
    <div id="slideM2" onmouseover="colorM(2)">Something 2</div>
    <div id="slideM3" onmouseover="colorM(3)">Something 3</div>
    <div id="slideM4" onmouseover="colorM(4)">Something 4</div>
    <div id="slideM5" onmouseover="colorM(5)">Something 5</div>
</div>
```

and this CSS

```
html, body{ 
    font-family: "Century Gothic", "Apple Gothic", AppleGothic, "URW Gothic L", "Avant Garde", Futura, sans-serif;
}
#slideMenu {
    float: right;
}
#slideM1:before, #slideM2:before, #slideM3:before, #slideM4:before, #slideM5:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:210px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 32px solid transparent;
    border-right: 30px solid #602F4F;
    border-bottom: 32px solid transparent;
    display:none;
}
#slideM1, #slideM2, #slideM3, #slideM4, #slideM5 {
    background-color: silver;
    height: 54px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

and finally this Javascript

```
function colorM(n) {
    document.getElementById("slideM"+n).style.backgroundColor="#602F4F";
    document.getElementById("slideM"+n+":before").style.display="block";
}
```

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xN6Da/ . As you can see CSS triangle has default value `display: none;`. But after it's hovered I want to change it's value to be visible. I tried to use `document.getElementById("slideM"+n+":before").style.display="block";` but it still hides the triangle, so how to remove that `display: none;` from CSS with Javascript?

Thank you

Comment: Pseudo elements (the css-generated `::before` and `::after`) are presentation-only, and are not (currently at least) available within the DOM. To adjust the styles you'd need to access the style rules in which the properties are defined and change those. Or add a class to the 'parent' element, and use that class to influence the colour.

Comment: So it's not possible to edit it while it's just one DIV?

Comment: Add/remove a class and do it with a CSS rule; it's extremely easy.  Your CSS would be simpler if you gave your slides a common class, so you wouldn't have to list out the "id" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify pseudo classes via Javascript. You will need to change it by adding/removing a class. For instance, by adding CSS like this:

```
#slideM1.show:before, #slideM2.show:before, #slideM3.show:before, #slideM4.show:before, #slideM5.show:before {
   display: block;
}
```

and this Javascript

```
function colorM(n) {
    document.getElementById("slideM"+n).style.backgroundColor="#602F4F";
    document.getElementById("slideM"+n+).className="show";
}
```

Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xN6Da/1/

I would recommend removing the IDs and replacing them with a common Class. Currently, every time you add another element. You are going to need to create another ID and add it to the CSS.

Comment: You posted a link to the *original* jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xN6Da/2/ I have finished this. Would you mind telling me how to remove that class again? Thank you.

Comment: You just need to do something like this. document.getElementById("slideM1").className=""; Setting the className to an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

If your asking how to change style rules via Javascript, this is the code I use:

```
//* Function: putClassAttrib((myclass,myatt,myval)
//* Purpose: Add/modify a rule in a given class
putClassAttrib = function(myclass,myatt,myval) {
  // e.g. putClassAttrib(".hideme","whiteSpace","nowrap")
  var myrules;  
  if (document.all) {
    myrules = 'rules';
    }
  else if (document.getElementById) {
    myrules = 'cssRules';
    }
  else {
    return "Prototype warning: no style rules changer for this browser"
    }
  for (var i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<document.styleSheets[i][myrules].length;j++) {
      if (document.styleSheets[i][myrules][j].selectorText == myclass) {
        document.styleSheets[i][myrules][j].style[myatt] = myval;
        }
      }
    }
  return ""; 
  }
```

(notice, I am an unrepentant advocate of banner style indenting ;-)... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Banner_style